# Can I mix DDR1 from different manufacturers?

Tags: ddr, dram

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I mix different RAM modules in PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/381726/can-i-mix-different-ram-modules-in-pc)

I've got an old computer with four DDR1 slots. Can I insert two sticks from Corsair and two sticks from another manufacturer (with a viking logo) without worrying? Or do I risk breaking something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a risk based on mixing different manufacturers. You may want to make sure the speed of the new ram is the same or greater to get the best results but even that would not cause problems/breaking something.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this should work just fine.  In fact, in most cases it does.  However, be aware that you're mixing vendors and be prepared to swap or isolate them as a troubleshooting step should you run into trouble.

There are other factors as well.  Many consumer/enthusiast motherboards require relaxed RAM timings when all slots are filled.